# DHTML: Css inheritance problem

Tags: html, css, inheritance

Hello I would like to use in my css simple inheritance from the browsers default values:

```
.myfromh1{
font-weight: bold;
}
```

Can I tell css that **.myfromh1** class is owning all properties of the **h1** default class?

thanks Arman.

Comment: Oh Sorry there was a typo: instead of "#" I need to have a "."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not quite clear from your question what you want to achieve. CSS uses a hierarchy of overwriting rules.

#### Inline styles have precedence over `<style>` block code

```
<style type="text/css">
#test { color: red; }
</style>

<span id="test" style="color: blue;">This text will be blue</span>
```

#### All styles have precedence over styles that are defined earlier in the code

```
<style type="text/css">
#test { color: red; }
#test { color: blue; }
</style>

<span id="test">This text will be blue</span>
```

#### Styles with high specificity have precedence over less specific styles

```
<style type="text/css">
#test { color: blue; }
.test { color: red; }
</style>

<span id="test" class="test">This text will be blue</span>
```

#### Some browsers honor the `!important` keyword

```
<style type="text/css">
span { color: blue !important; }
#test { color: red; }

<span id="test">This text should be blue</span>
```

Therefore, to answer your question, if your element is a `H1` element, then it will automatically have all the properties of a `h1` selector, and only those that are *overridden* by the `#myfromh1` selector will be changed.

If, however, you're looking for true inheritance between selectors - if `#myfromh1` is not a H1 element, but you want it to be styled like one, then the answer is that that cannot be achieved in CSS.

Comment: Thanks for detail answer. That's pity that I cannot apply h1 styling to  the give div.

Comment: @Arman: yes! inheritance and variables are two of the things i miss most in css. if you've got access to do server side stuff such as PHP or .NET, you could create your own pseudo-css markup and create that to *render* css files, and work around your problem like that, but that is a different question entirely.

Comment: Yes, that's right, I am able to do tricks from server side. Redesigning old site is always ends with headaches:).

Answer (score 1):

```
h1#myfromh1{
font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: what is this answer supposed to mean?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just give the id **myfromh1** to a `<h1>`-HTML element.

Comment: but, I would like to apply h1 property to <div class="myfromh1">Blah will be in h1</div>